# .ashx - The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, ashx

I am giving two calls to one remote `REST service` one after the other in single method. I am setting value of `accessToken` in first call and using it for the second request.

When I am running it, it is giving me error as

`The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.`

Following is the code.

```
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
    HttpWebResponse webResponse = null;
    Encoding encodingObj = null;
    StreamReader streamReaderObj = null;

    string grantCode = string.Empty;
    string resultString = string.Empty;
    string accessToken = string.Empty;

    private void Instantiate()
    {            
        grantCode = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["code"].ToString();
        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN_REQUEST + "&code=" + grantCode);
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        encodingObj = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        streamReaderObj = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), encodingObj);
        resultString = streamReaderObj.ReadToEnd();
        JObject parameterCollection = JObject.Parse(resultString);
        accessToken = parameterCollection["access_token"].ToString();
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br/><br/>Code: <br/>" + grantCode);
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br/><br/>Access Token: <br/>" + accessToken);

        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Constants.RETRIEVE_CONTEXT_REQUEST + "vista-688/id/Staff01");
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        encodingObj = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        streamReaderObj = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), encodingObj);
        resultString = streamReaderObj.ReadToEnd();
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br/><br/>Retrieve Context: <br/>" + resultString);
    }
```

These are full rest api URLs from config files:

```
<add key="GrantCodeRequest" value="https://<location>/AuthorizationServices/provider/authorize?response_type=code&state=mystateid&client_id=mVisum&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1316/RetrieveContext.aspx&scope=read"/>
<add key="AccessTokenRequest" value="https://<location>/AuthorizationServices/oauth/token?client_id=mVisum&state=mystateid&scope=read&client_secret=TESTMVISUM&response_type=token&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1316/RetrieveContext.aspx"/>
<add key="RetrieveContextRequest" value="http://<location>/UserContext/rest/context/user/system/"/>
```

When I am doing only second request with `accessToken` value initialized to valid value second call is also working without any exception. This method is written in one handler.

Can any one tell me why this is happening? There is no issue in REST web service. I have also tried by using two separate web request and web response objects but nothing is working out

Comment: So the *browser* is showing you a 500 error, but what's the exception occurring in your code? Have you tried catching any exceptions with a `try/catch` block?

Comment: What is the full url of the rservice when debuging?

Comment: @Cory yes. It is simply showing the same error. No inner exception.

Comment: @kostasch. Please check edited question for the full urls

Comment: Try without url http://localhost:1316/RetrieveContext.aspx

Comment: @kostasch. this value is important as after successful request REST redirects to this URL

Comment: You can do this programmaticaly. You can just try it. If in url use / to set parameters for sure you have problem with dots, but in that you use parameters.

Comment: it is not working after removing that URL

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers["Content-type"] = @"application/json";
        Stream data = client.OpenRead(yoururl); ;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The above works fine for me.